# npm ERR! code EBUSY npm ERR syscall unlink npm ERR! path C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\3b3a44cd npm ERR errno EBUSY npm ERR

Tags: npm, npm-cache

I am facing this issue from more than 1 year, I tried everything to solve the issue but nothing works. All the solutions work sometimes only, but then this issue appears again:

> npm ERR! code EBUSY
> npm ERR! syscall unlink
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Local\npm-cache_cacache\tmp\3b3a44cd
> npm ERR! errno EBUSY
> npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@vitejs%2fplugin-react: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink 'C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Local\npm-cache_cacache\tmp\3b3a44cd'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-01-06T08_22_17_506Z-debug-0.log

I tried deleting the `npm-cache` folder:

```
npm cache clear --force
```

I tried installing and uninstalling node and npm:

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
```

I also inform npm support regarding this issue but there suggestion is also not worked for me hence they told me to post the issue here.

File of `npm-cache > logs`

```
2024-01-04T09_44_37_815Z-debug-0.log
:
2024-01-04T09_44_38_349Z-debug-0.log
2024-01-04T09_45_26_491Z-debug-0.log
2024-01-04T09_45_27_040Z-debug-0.log
2024-01-04T09_45_32_803Z-debug-0.log
2024-01-04T09_45_33_360Z-debug-0.log
2024-01-04T09_45_47_119Z-debug-0.log
2024-01-04T09_45_47_664Z-debug-0.log

2024-01-04T09_43_41_220Z-debug-0.log
2024-01-04T09_43_41_867Z-debug-0.log
2024-01-04T09_46_32_584Z-debug-0.log
```